# Remove and add markers with zoom in and out

Tags: ios, google-maps, gmsmapview

In one of my project (IOS) I need to add functionality that when user zoom out the google maps it adds marks within that coordinates. Right now I am zooming the map on user current location and the nearest location. So when user zoom out it will add more locations that are in that region. I dont know how to achieve that please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

As it looks like, GoogleMaps SDK leaves the responsibility for storing and managing markers entirely to you. 
So what you need to do is keep a separate storage (like `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableSet` or whatever best suits you) for all your markers and using `projection.visibleRegion` property on `GMSMapView` to decide which to remove (or add).

Check out [GMSProjection reference on GoogleMaps SDK docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection.html)

In order to catch up with zooming in and out, you have to declare your `GMSMapViewDelegate` and implement this method:

`- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position`

That's about it.